# Verify ImageMagick installation

Tags: php, imagemagick

My web hosting said ImageMagic has been pre-installed on the server. I did a quick search for "ImageMagick" in the output of phpinfo() and I found nothing. I can't SSH in the server so is there a way in PHP I can verify the installation?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
//This function prints a text array as an html list.
function alist ($array) {  
  $alist = "<ul>";
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    $alist .= "<li>$array[$i]";
  }
  $alist .= "</ul>";
  return $alist;
}
//Try to get ImageMagick "convert" program version number.
exec("convert -version", $out, $rcode);
//Print the return code: 0 if OK, nonzero if error. 
echo "Version return code is $rcode <br>"; 
//Print the output of "convert -version"    
echo alist($out); 
?>
```

Comment: this tests if ImageMagick application is installed, not the PHP module

Comment: Version return code is 0

    * Version: ImageMagick 6.3.7 08/09/09 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
    * Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2008 ImageMagick Studio LLC

Comment: this is what the page returns. seems it's having trouble returning the version but somehow returns the copyright info.

Comment: The answer may work, but the two below are much simpler, easier and obvious. Is this a good reason for down-voting this one?

Comment: It's a solution that worked for the person asking the question. Down-voting is not for correct answers. If you have a question about etiquette you should ask it in meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: `Version return code is 4 ` what is the meaning of this ?

Comment: @wajiw That's not true. It is ambiguous because he meant the php-imagick module. This script just checks for the ImageMagick Distribution / convert binary, not the php-imagick module which is what he actually meant. So this answer is not only false, it generates a false positive result which is worse.

Answer (score 175):

This is as short and sweet as it can get:

```
if (!extension_loaded('imagick')){
    echo 'imagick not installed';
}
```

Comment: Similarly, from the command line: `php -r 'echo "imagick is ".(extension_loaded("imagick")?"":"not ")."installed\n";'`

Answer (score 44):

EDIT: The info and script below only applies to iMagick class - which is not added by default with ImageMagick!!!

If I want to know if imagemagick is installed and actually working as a php extension, I paste this snippet into a web accessible file

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');

/* Create a new imagick object */
$im = new Imagick();

/* Create new image. This will be used as fill pattern */
$im->newPseudoImage(50, 50, "gradient:red-black");

/* Create imagickdraw object */
$draw = new ImagickDraw();

/* Start a new pattern called "gradient" */
$draw->pushPattern('gradient', 0, 0, 50, 50);

/* Composite the gradient on the pattern */
$draw->composite(Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0, 50, 50, $im);

/* Close the pattern */
$draw->popPattern();

/* Use the pattern called "gradient" as the fill */
$draw->setFillPatternURL('#gradient');

/* Set font size to 52 */
$draw->setFontSize(52);

/* Annotate some text */
$draw->annotation(20, 50, "Hello World!");

/* Create a new canvas object and a white image */
$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newImage(350, 70, "white");

/* Draw the ImagickDraw on to the canvas */
$canvas->drawImage($draw);

/* 1px black border around the image */
$canvas->borderImage('black', 1, 1);

/* Set the format to PNG */
$canvas->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image */
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $canvas;
?>
```

You should see a hello world graphic:

[image]

Answer (score 35):

In bash:

```
$ convert -version
```

or

```
$ /usr/local/bin/convert -version
```

No need to write any PHP file just to check.

Comment: Just to save anyone else having to look it up - convert is the shell command imagick installs so the above talks to it directly to check that it's there +1

Answer (score 19):

You can easily check for the Imagick class in PHP.

```
if( class_exists("Imagick") )
{
    //Imagick is installed
}
```

Comment: **important:** Sometimes this returns FALSE but `extension_loaded('imagick')` returns TRUE !, so I guess better is: `if( extension_loaded('imagick') || class_exists("Imagick") ){ /*do Imagick*/ }`

Comment: I've seen `class_exists(Imagick::class)` used before. That might be more reliable.

Answer (score 17):

In Bash you can check if Imagick is an installed module:

```
$ php -m | grep imagick
```

If the response is blank it is not installed.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one-shot solution that should figure out where ImageMagick is, if you have access to it...

This found all versions on my Godaddy hosting.

Upload this file to your server and call it `ImageMagick.php` or something then run it. You will get all the info you need... hopefully...

Good luck.

```
<?
/*
// This file will run a test on your server to determine the location and versions of ImageMagick. 
//It will look in the most commonly found locations. The last two are where most popular hosts (including "Godaddy") install ImageMagick.
//
// Upload this script to your server and run it for a breakdown of where ImageMagick is.
//
*/
echo '<h2>Test for versions and locations of ImageMagick</h2>';
echo '<b>Path: </b> convert<br>';

function alist ($array) {  //This function prints a text array as an html list.
    $alist = "<ul>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
        $alist .= "<li>$array[$i]";
    }
    $alist .= "</ul>";
    return $alist;
}

exec("convert -version", $out, $rcode); //Try to get ImageMagick "convert" program version number.
echo "Version return code is $rcode <br>"; //Print the return code: 0 if OK, nonzero if error.
echo alist($out); //Print the output of "convert -version"
echo '<br>';
echo '<b>This should test for ImageMagick version 5.x</b><br>';
echo '<b>Path: </b> /usr/bin/convert<br>';

exec("/usr/bin/convert -version", $out, $rcode); //Try to get ImageMagick "convert" program version number.
echo "Version return code is $rcode <br>"; //Print the return code: 0 if OK, nonzero if error.
echo alist($out); //Print the output of "convert -version"

echo '<br>';
echo '<b>This should test for ImageMagick version 6.x</b><br>';
echo '<b>Path: </b> /usr/local/bin/convert<br>';

exec("/usr/local/bin/convert -version", $out, $rcode); //Try to get ImageMagick "convert" program version number.
echo "Version return code is $rcode <br>"; //Print the return code: 0 if OK, nonzero if error.
echo alist($out); //Print the output of "convert -version";

?>
```

Comment: convert a pdf: Many thx. nice script. worked well on both hostgator and godaddy... not as cool as cloud or AWS, but within the budget of my small business customers.

Comment: After hours... here Google eat this: MediaWiki Error creating thumbnail: sh: /usr/local/bin/convert: No such file or directory

Comment: Mine is a .NET and Sitecore based application. How do I check for my application if it's using ImageMagick or not?

Answer (score 5):

To test only the IMagick PHP extension (not the full ImageMagick suite), save the following as a PHP file (testImagick.php) and then run it from console: php testImagick.php

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(1, 1, new ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$pngData = $image->getImagesBlob();
echo strpos($pngData, "\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n") === 0 ? 'Ok' : 'Failed';
echo "\n";
```

credit: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html

Answer (score 1):

If your ISP/hosting service has installed ImageMagick and put its location in the PATH environment variable, you can find what versions are installed and where using:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
system("type -a convert");  
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that after installing Imagick (or indeed any PHP module) you need to restart your web server and/or php-fpm if you're using it, for the module to appear in phpinfo().