# ImageMagick and Typo3

Tags: installation, imagemagick, typo3, graphicsmagick

The [system requirements of TYPO3](https://typo3.org/about/typo3-the-cms/system-requirements/) are stating that I can use GraphicsMagic or ImageMagick. On the host I'm getting the following error `No ImageMagick installation available`.

I tried to verify with this question [Verify ImageMagick installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4208253/426227) if ImageMagick is installed and I get no version output.

Also there are some functions disabled like `exec()`. The install tool writes

> Possibly these functions are disabled due to security risks and most likely the list would include a function like exec() which is use by TYPO3 to access ImageMagick.

`im_version_5` is set to `im6`. Before I had ImageMagick but now the webspace is another one. Therefore I get this warning in `Image Processing`:

> Mismatch between the version of ImageMagick () and the configuration of [GFX][im_version_5] (im6)

Now I cannot make the test because they are skipped. Also if a user uploads a photo he cannot see the preview image in the backend.

My current settings:

```
[GFX][gdlib] = 1
[GFX][im] = 0
```

So GraphicsMagick is enabled and ImageMagick disabled. But it still makes problems.

So what should I do?

- Should I ask the hoster to enable `exec()`?
- Or is ImageMagick not installed?
- Other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask your hoster if ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is installed and if, what the correct path should be.
Also ask if exec() is disabled.

Comment: I got the message from my hoster that `exec()` has been enabled. Now it works except of PDF and AI files.

Comment: PDF and AI files need further programs on the webserver. Or try to switch to ``ImageMagick``.