# How to configure imagick / ImageMagick on ipage?

Tags: php, module, configuration, imagick

[Ipage says they are running ImageMagick 6.3.3](http://members.ipage.com/knowledgebase/read_article.bml?kbid=604) however, it is not running on the server and there is no way I can find how to enable it. They do not allow to configure any module from control panel.

I contacted support but they could not help saying, it is not 'their' product. Anybody can help setting up Imagick on ipage? I tried to edit php.ini file and reference to php_imagick.dll but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: `.dll`-files are Windows only, so unless you're using a Windows host, it won't do anything either way. I would contact the support again and persist that it's their issue to solve, or get your money back. If they promote that it suppose to be installed, it's up to them to fix it if it isn't.

Comment: your are write about dll. May be I will experiment with other extentions. Yes have to contact them again but if anyone has done it, we should resolve this here.

Comment: ImageMagick and Imagick are two separate tools. The latter depends upon the former. ImageMagick 6.3.3 is ancient (over 650 versions old).

Comment: If the hosts are running that old a version of Imagemagick I assume the underlying operating system is old as the later version of centos etc. install a 6.5 version which is also old. I recommend changing hosts and finding a more helpful one. Check with them first if they have Imagick installed and what versions Imagemagick is. Otherwise your other option is Imagemagick with exec() but it will be missing a lot of the later options. Out of interest have you checked what version of Imagemagick they are actually running as that knowledge page may never have been updated?

Comment: @Bonzo I checked the version using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4208290/777982).  Actual version returned is `Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org`. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: It was worth checking then; I find most Knowledge bases never get updated.

Answer (score 0):

**iPage does not support Imagick in PHP**

This is their official response after conctacting support

> We have ImageMagick binaries. But it is not complied to PHP so IMAGICK
>   won't work. So, you will not be able to use IMAGICK as PHP built-in
>   class. You have to use the alternative "convert" utility. Please make
>   changes accordingly in the script so that it will work fine on our
>   servers.

So basically you have to use exec() in PHP to use the Imagemagick `convert` command. Also you cannot use convert command from a shell environment as for as I know.

But there is GD commands available on ipage and for the most part they would be enough for all graphic related functions. In fact in my case, I found that they were rather moreful.

Comment: I use exec( ) with Imagemagick convert on my sites without problems; I am not sure what a shell environment is. But if GD does what you want go with it.

Comment: Ipage does not provie shell (SSH) environment only so it looks like exec() is the only way to go if needed. GD is perfect for me though and that's all I need for now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I got from iPage is that PHP Imagick is not available on the Essential Package. To get PHP Imagick I would need to sign up for VPS hosting which is more expensive. For now I am giong to ignore the recommendation from Wordpress to install PHP Imagick. I have installed the Wordpress "ImageMagick Engine" plugin and it is now working with no errors.