# imagick extension not showing up in phpinfo on Amazon linux

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, centos, imagemagick, amazon-linux

I am using AWS EC2 and installed the Imagemagick and php imagick extension using the below steps:

**Steps**

1. `cd ImageMagick-6.7.8-9` - go where you placed the folder
2. `./configure`
3. `make`
4. `make install`
5. `make check`
6. install imagick extension from pecl.php.net/package/imagick/download 3.1.2
7. `cd imagick-3.1.2`
8. `phpize`
9. `./configure --with-imagick=/opt/local`
10. `make`
11. `make install`
12. Copy imagick.so in your PHP extensions folder and add extension=imagick.so in php.ini

When I run `php -m | grep imagick`, I get the below warning:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
imagick
```

When I run `convert -version`, it shows the below message

> Version: ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2016-06-22 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
>   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
>   Features: OpenMP

When I run `php -m`, it shows Imagick in the list. But `print run phpinfo()` does not show Imagick.

**Also when I am trying to create the instance of Imagick it is giving Fatal Error that Class not found.**

Comment: Maybe [try the solution in the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22438898/499581), and then report back.

Comment: as soon as I create an instance of Imagick in PHP.... it is throwing fatal error that class not found and also imagick is not showing up when I print phpinfo().